# Frequentist vs Bayesian Linear Gaussian Models

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, estimation, frequentist

Consider the following linear Gaussian system:

[image]

where $p(x)$ is our prior. The Bayesian inference problem can be expressed in **closed-form** as<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

Where can I find an equivalent "frequentist" estimation procedure? Can they also be expressed in closed form?

---

<sup>1</sup> *"Machine Learning - A Probabilistic Perspective"*, 2012, pp. 119. Kevin Murphy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear what you mean by frequentist estimation, but I'll take a stab.

This problem is regression with a known covariance matrix where 
$$
Y-b \sim N(Ax,\Sigma_y).
$$

The only unknown here is $x$, so the maximum likelihood estimator is 
$$
\hat{x}_{MLE} = \text{argmax}_{x} p(y|x) = [A^T\Sigma_y^{-1}A]^{-1}A^T \Sigma_y^{-1}(y-b)
$$
which is the posterior mode in the limit as $\Sigma_x^{-1}\to 0$, i.e. the improper uniform distribution.

The sampling distribution for $\hat{x}_{MLE}$ is normal with mean 
$$
[A^T\Sigma_y^{-1}A]^{-1}A^T \Sigma_y^{-1}A x
$$
and covariance matrix 
$$
A[A^T\Sigma_y^{-1}A]^{-1}[A^T\Sigma_y^{-1}A]^{-1}A^T.
$$ 
The sampling distribution can be used to construct confidence, i.e. frequentist, intervals.

Comment: Thanks @jaradniemi. This is great; right what I was looking for. Any particular papers or textbooks you recommend that cover sampling distributions of these types of systems? (e.g. I am interested on similar derivations for a mixture of Beta-Binomial variables).